# select class within first child li

Tags: css, class, css-selectors

So i've been wondering how i could effect a class with only the first child of an li.
so here it is placing the 3 images for every element of the li. But my problem is that on li's first child the placement is wrong.

```
.sf-menu > li > ul > li.category-thumbnail > div {
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 100px;
    padding-top: 30px;
}
.sf-menu > li > ul > li.category-thumbnail > div:first-child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 135px;
  right: 180px !important;
  }
.sf-menu > li > ul > li.category-thumbnail > div:nth-child(2) {
  position: absolute;
  right: 180px !important;
  }
.sf-menu > li > ul > li.category-thumbnail > div:nth-child(3) {
  position: absolute;
  right: 553px !important;
  }
```

And I would like to add something like:

```
.sf-menu > li > ul > li:first-child.category-thumbnail > div:first-child {..}
.sf-menu > li > ul > li:first-child.category-thumbnail > div:nth-child(2) {..}
.sf-menu > li > ul > li:first-child.category-thumbnail > div:nth-child(3) {..}
```

thanks in advance for your help

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: there's no html, it's a php an jquery coded thing. It's a prestashop module.

Answer (score 0):

I do believe that this:

```
.sf-menu > li > ul > li.category-thumbnail > div:first-child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 135px;
  right: 180px !important;
}
```

targets the first child of the div, and not the actual li.

try something like this:

```
.sf-menu > li > ul > li.category-thumbnail:first-child > div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 135px;
  right: 180px !important;
}
```

or:

```
.sf-menu > li:first-child > ul > li.category-thumbnail > div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 135px;
  right: 180px !important;
}
```

Comment: The thing is that i want to get effect on the first picture in category thumbnail in the first child of li in .sf-menu li ul li (<- this li)

Answer (score 0):

Thank all for answering. I finally founded the solution. it was:

.sf-menu > ***li:first-child*** > ul > li.category-thumbnail > div:first-child